# Python: finding a list in an numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm looking for positions of pixels with the same colour in a RGB-Screenshot.

```
def ScreenToArray(box):
  Screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)
  return np.array(Screenshot)

def GetCoordiantes(array, colourWanted):
  coordiantes = np.where(array == colourWanted)
  xyCoordiantes = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])]
  return xyCoordiantes

box = (200, 300, 400, 600)
colourWanted = [200, 200, 200]
ScreenArray = ScreenToArray(box)
PixelsCoordinates = GetCoordinates(ScreenArray, colourWanted)
```

The code works fine until there is a pixel the `ScreenArray` that shares a number with my wanted colour.

Why does `numpy.where(array == [200, 200, 200])` also return the coordinates for list entries like `[[200, 1, 1]]`, and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this looking dumb but worked

```
def getcoor(img,color):
    indxs,_=np.where(img==color)
    return [indxs[i] for i in range(len(indxs)-2) if indxs[i]==indxs[i+1] and indxs[i+1]==indxs[i+2]]
```